# Failed to delete default.mysql8.0: Default DBParameterGroup cannot be deleted: default.mysql8.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to delete the default DB parameter group after deletion of AWS RDS MySQL database but is giving the following error

[image]

```sh
Failed to delete default.mysql8.0: Default DBParameterGroup cannot be deleted: default.mysql8.0 (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDBParameterGroupState;
```

Not sure why its not getting deleted.
Tried referencing this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteDBParameterGroup.html) and it says it might be in invalid state but how do I validate that ?

### Initial State When No RDS instances were created

[image]

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear as to why you can't remove the group?

Comment: hehe, no it definitely makes sense :). Thank you so much for your help. You are amazing @Marcin .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`default.mysql8.0` is a **default** parameter group, and you can't delete default groups. From your [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteDBParameterGroup.html):

> You **can't delete** a default DB parameter group

Comment: Thanks a lot @marcin. So once it get's created we cannot delete it? Because it was definitely not present before.

Comment: @codeaprendiz You can't create a default group. They already exisit. Maybe you haven't noticed it before?

Comment: I validated again. The default parameter group before we create any RDS instances is 0. I have added the screenshot :) . Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @codeaprendiz Interesting. Maybe it did not appear to you before creating a rds instance. But the point is, that this is a default parameter group, and you can't modify nor delete it.

Comment: It's very annoying because once you create an RDS then delete it, you will forever have this group sitting there in AWS Tag Editor and there's no way to remove it again, even if you don't use RDS anywhere in your account.